# Eager loading associated data with Knex and Objection.js

Tags: express, knex.js, objection.js

I have an Express api using Postgresql for data storage, Knex/Objection for queries and modeling.

I have two models Users and Posts s.t. User has_many Posts and Post belongs_to User.

I am trying to return the associated User object to a specific post, like post.user, but I am getting an error

Here are my Objection models:

BaseModel:

```
</src/models/BaseModel.js>

const { Model } = require('objection');

class BaseModel extends Model {
  $beforeInsert() {
    const now = new Date().toISOString();
    this.created_at = now;
    this.updated_at = now;
  }

  $beforeUpdate() {
    const now = new Date().toISOString();
    this.updated_at = now;
  }

}

module.exports = BaseModel;
```

Users model:

```
<src/models/User.js>

const BaseModel = require("./BaseModel");
// const Password = require('objection-password')();

class User extends BaseModel {
  static get tableName() {
    return "users";
  }

  static get relationMappings () {
    return {
      posts: {
        relation: Model.HasManyRelation,
        modelClass: Post,
        join: {
          from: 'users.id',
          to: 'posts.users_id'
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

module.exports = User;
```

and Posts model:

```
</src/models/Post.js>



        const BaseModel = require("./BaseModel");
const User = require('./User');

// const Password = require('objection-password')();

class Post extends BaseModel {
  static get tableName() {
    return "posts";
  }

  static get relationMappings () {
    return {
      user: {
        relation: BaseModel.BelongsToOneRelation,
        modelClass: User,
        join: {
          from: 'posts.users_id',
          to: 'users.id'
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

module.exports = Post;
```

here is my route/ query:

```
const express = require('express');
const User = require('../models/User');
const Post = require('../models/Post');

let router = express.Router();

router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  const posts = await Post
    .query().eager('users');
  res.json(posts);
});

module.exports = router;
```

and here is the error trace:

```
Running on localhost:8000
```

(node:32230) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ValidationError: unknown relation "users" in an eager expression
    at Function.createValidationError (/Users/dariusgoore/development/writtr-app/writerboard-express-api/node_modules/objection/lib/model/Model.js:397:12)
    at findRelationsToFetch (/Users/dariusgoore/development/writtr-app/writerboard-express-api/node_modules/objection/lib/queryBuilder/operations/eager/WhereInEagerOperation.js:166:24)
    at WhereInEagerOperation.onBuild (/Users/dariusgoore/development/writtr-app/writerboard-express-api/node_modules/objection/lib/queryBuilder/operations/eager/WhereInEagerOperation.js:36:30)
    at QueryBuilder.callOperationMethod (/Users/dariusgoore/development/writtr-app/writerboard-express-api/node_modules/objection/lib/queryBuilder/QueryBuilderOperationSupport.js:345:33)
    at forEachOperation.op (/Users/dariusgoore/development/writtr-app/writerboard-express-api/node_modules/objection/lib/queryBuilder/QueryBuilderOperationSupport.js:437:14)
    at QueryBuilder.forEachOperation (/Users/dariusgoore/development/writtr-app/writerboard-express-api/node_modules/objection/lib/queryBuilder/QueryBuilderOperationSupport.js:282:37)
    at QueryBuilder.executeOnBuild (/Users/dariusgoore/development/writtr-app/writerboard-express-api/node_modules/objection/lib/queryBuilder/QueryBuilderOperationSupport.js:435:10)
    at callOnBuildHooks (/Users/dariusgoore/development/writtr-app/writerboard-express-api/node_modules/objection/lib/queryBuilder/QueryBuilder.js:1363:11)
    at doExecute (/Users/dariusgoore/development/writtr-app/writerboard-express-api/node_modules/objection/lib/queryBuilder/QueryBuilder.js:1253:13)
    at Bluebird.try.then (/Users/dariusgoore/development/writtr-app/writerboard-express-api/node_modules/objection/lib/queryBuilder/QueryBuilder.js:573:19)
From previous event:
    at QueryBuilder.execute (/Users/dariusgoore/development/writtr-app/writerboard-express-api/node_modules/objection/lib/queryBuilder/QueryBuilder.js:573:8)
    at QueryBuilder.then (/Users/dariusgoore/development/writtr-app/writerboard-express-api/node_modules/objection/lib/queryBuilder/QueryBuilder.js:490:26)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
(node:32230) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
(node:32230) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
^[[1;2C(node:32230) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ValidationError: unknown relation "users" in an eager expression
    at Function.createValidationError (/Users/dariusgoore/development/writtr-app/writerboard-express-api/node_modules/objection/lib/model/Model.js:397:12)
    at findRelationsToFetch (/Users/dariusgoore/development/writtr-app/writerboard-express-api/node_modules/objection/lib/queryBuilder/operations/eager/WhereInEagerOperation.js:166:24)
    at WhereInEagerOperation.onBuild (/Users/dariusgoore/development/writtr-app/writerboard-express-api/node_modules/objection/lib/queryBuilder/operations/eager/WhereInEagerOperation.js:36:30)
    at QueryBuilder.callOperationMethod (/Users/dariusgoore/development/writtr-app/writerboard-express-api/node_modules/objection/lib/queryBuilder/QueryBuilderOperationSupport.js:345:33)
    at forEachOperation.op (/Users/dariusgoore/development/writtr-app/writerboard-express-api/node_modules/objection/lib/queryBuilder/QueryBuilderOperationSupport.js:437:14)
    at QueryBuilder.forEachOperation (/Users/dariusgoore/development/writtr-app/writerboard-express-api/node_modules/objection/lib/queryBuilder/QueryBuilderOperationSupport.js:282:37)
    at QueryBuilder.executeOnBuild (/Users/dariusgoore/development/writtr-app/writerboard-express-api/node_modules/objection/lib/queryBuilder/QueryBuilderOperationSupport.js:435:10)
    at callOnBuildHooks (/Users/dariusgoore/development/writtr-app/writerboard-express-api/node_modules/objection/lib/queryBuilder/QueryBuilder.js:1363:11)
    at doExecute (/Users/dariusgoore/development/writtr-app/writerboard-express-api/node_modules/objection/lib/queryBuilder/QueryBuilder.js:1253:13)
    at Bluebird.try.then (/Users/dariusgoore/development/writtr-app/writerboard-express-api/node_modules/objection/lib/queryBuilder/QueryBuilder.js:573:19)
From previous event:
    at QueryBuilder.execute (/Users/dariusgoore/development/writtr-app/writerboard-express-api/node_modules/objection/lib/queryBuilder/QueryBuilder.js:573:8)
    at QueryBuilder.then (/Users/dariusgoore/development/writtr-app/writerboard-express-api/node_modules/objection/lib/queryBuilder/QueryBuilder.js:490:26)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
(node:32230) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 4)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok solved this.

Changed route query to:

```
router.get('/', async (req, res) => {

  const posts = await Post
    .query().eager('user');
  res.json(posts);
});
```